# Change cell color based on amount of time passed

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm hitting a brick wall. What I'm trying to do is change the color of my "waiting" cell in my table based off the amount of time that has passed. When queried my "waiting" cell displays a time stamp in the format of 00:00:00. To make my coding more consistent and easier for the next guy who may come along and replace me. I'm querying a view that I created within my mysql database that updates my timestamp. So, all my html/php code has to do is query the view to pull in the information I want displayed.

I've scoured the internet and found several bits and pieces of code that it supposed to be able to change a cells color based on value. I've had a little bit of luck but have not gained the desired results. I either end up with cells that stay the same color and not change or find there is something wrong with the code that prevents the whole page from loading.

```
include 'config/database.php';
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$records_per_page = 5;
$from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page; 
$query = "SELECT ptfin, ptname, ptdob, pore, notes, labstat,
                 rtstat,radstat,waiting 
            FROM dashboard_view 
            WHERE ( labstat != '' AND labstat IS NOT NULL) 
               OR (radstat != '' AND radstat IS NOT NULL) 
               OR (rtstat != '' AND rtstat IS NOT NULL) 
            ORDER BY waiting DESC 
            LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":from_record_num", $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":records_per_page", $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();


$curDate = time();
$mysqlTimestamp = $row['waiting']; //This is the piece of code that is giving me issues. 
$dif = strtotime($curdate) - strtotime($mysqlTimestamp);

if($num>0) 
    if($dif < 10000) {
        $tdStyle='background-color:green;';
    } else {
        $tdStyle='background-color:red;';
    }

    echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>FIN#</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>PorE</th>";
        echo "<th>Notes</th>";
        echo "<th>Modalities</th>";
        echo "<th>Waiting</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        extract($row);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width=15>{$ptfin}</td>";
        echo "<td width=100>{$ptname}</td>";
        echo "<td width=5>{$pore}</td>";
        echo "<td width=200>{$notes}</td>";
        echo "<td width=170><img src=".$labstat." ><img src=".$rtstat." ><img src=".$radstat." ></td>";
        echo "<td style=\"$tdStyle\" width=50>{$waiting}</td>";
        //echo "<td width=5>{$dif}</td>"; code for testing visual output of timestamp mathmatics

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

What I would like to have happen is if the timestamp is less than 10 minutes the cell displays green. If the timestamp falls into the range of 10 to 15 minutes to the cell displays yellow. If the timestamp is greater than 15 minutes the cell displays red.

Comment: How are you reloading the whole page or how the data on your page gets updated? Are you using JavaScript? Are you familier with the concept of AJAX?

Comment: This is how I actually refresh the whole page. echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='20' />"; I've had folks tell me what I'm asking could possibly be done with java and or ajax. However, I'm not at all familiar with those enough to even know really where to begin.

Comment: To begin with JavaScript and Ajax [https://www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com) is a good source to read. Later, you can move to advance tutorials but for the begginers it can be really helpful.

Comment: And please keep in mind that java and JavaScript are two totally different languages.

Comment: And one more thing, where is the code to change the color with time in the snippet in your question? I am unable to see any color attribute used in the code.

Comment: Sorry it was late and I didn't realize I just copied my unaltered base code. I've updated my code to reflect what I'm trying to make happen at bare minimum.

Comment: if($waiting < 600) {
    $tdStyle='background-color:green;';
} else {
    $tdStyle='background-color:red;';
}

Comment: echo "<td width=170><img src=".$labstat." ><img src=".$rtstat." ><img src=".$radstat." ></td>";

Comment: This sorta of works. It changes the cell background depending upon which direction I moved the < symbol. It' just doesn't do it on the amount of time that has passed. I was thinking it was counting in seconds. So, I put 600 down which is 10 minutes. I've tried 00:10:00 and that caused the page not to load. I feel like I'm about there but just missing a small detail.

Comment: Try using a smaller interval for testing, just to make sure you see something.

Comment: I've done some experimenting and changing the interval did not make a difference. I think my problem is that it would appear that my "if" statement isn't able to either see or pull the info it needs from the database. So what I did to prove this is I added $waiting1 = 0; to my code and changed my if statement to read if($waiting1 <1).  I'm finding that changing the $waiting1=0 variable to any other than 0 produces the results I want. Now it's just a matter of figuring out what I need to have so I don't have to do it manually.